# Create centered gaussian blur mask on image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I tried to create a gaussian noise mask which should be overlayed over my image with dimension sizeX, sizeY. I have found a way to do so by using the meshgrid function and it worked out fine:

```
function gaussian = GetGaussNoiseImage(sizeX, sizeY, A, std) 
indicator = -floor(sizeX/2) : floor(sizeY/2);
[X Y] = meshgrid(indicator, indicator);
h = exp(-(X.^2 + Y.^2) / (2*std^2));
mesh(h);
```

My first approach though was the following:

```
function gaussian = GetGaussNoiseImage(sizeX, sizeY, A, std)
[sizeX sizeY] = size(I)
centerX = sizeX/2;
centerY = sizeY/2;
gaussian = zeros(sizeX, sizeY); 

for i = 1:sizeX
    for j = 1:sizeY
        gaussian(i, j) = A.*exp(- ((i - centerX).^2 + (j - centerY).^2 )/2*std^2);
    end
end
mesh(gaussian);
```

For me it is exactly the same aproach with the difference of including two for-loops. For some reason it does not want to function though. Can anybody explain to me what I did wrong?

Here is the my output image:

[image: output].

Comment: What does "does not want to function" mean? It caused an error? It doesn't show the right result? What's wrong? Show the expected and current outputs to help...

Comment: No matter how I change the parameters (std, A, Image size etc.) I get a Zero-by-Zero Matrix...

Comment: `std` is the parameter to change. But what are you triying to do? gaussian blur is achieved by convolving a gaussian kernel, not by overlying it.

Comment: yes thats right but it was my way to check whether it works or not..
with overlaying i mean that I want to have a local central blurring (not the total Image) which would be located in the middle at sizeX/2 and sizeY/2.

sorry for the formulation it was probably a bit "sloppy" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the equation for the Gaussian. You write:

```
gaussian(i, j) = A.*exp(- ((i - centerX).^2 + (j - centerY).^2 )/2*std^2);
```

But you should instead do:

```
gaussian(i, j) = A.*exp(- ((i - centerX).^2 + (j - centerY).^2 )/ ( 2*std^2 ) );
                                                                  ^         ^
```

Note the added brackets! You have these in the first code snippet, but forgot them in the second.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great help! These are things that I always seem to forget....